# Регистрация приложения в Instagram

Tags: instagram

Добрый день.
Зарегистрировал приложение в Instagram.

Получил полный доступ к API(**basic+comments+relationships+likes**).

Когда начинаю посылать запросы, то **GET** уходит нормально, а на **POST** приходит вот такой ответ

"We've taken extra measures to protect the Instagram API from abnormal activity. Since you have recently created your API application, please contact **apidevelopers@instagram.com** to receive whitelisting for a higher rate limit."

Писал им на этот адрес, но до сих пор не пришло никакого ответа. 
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1):

Как пишут в интернетах: возможно это потому, что приложение делает больше 350 лайков в час. Вы попадаете под этот критерий?

Совет: старайтесь избегать тестирования лайков на живом API.

Если у вас уже готовое приложение и только проблема с white-list, то может быть стоит просто получить новый ключ доступа? Тогда по идее, вы ещё не будете забанены за кучу лайков.